# Incorrect Hibernate HQL / DAO function / while coding Spring Security - Annotations

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I learn the hibernate framework and I am so confused with generated sql.
I have the following code:

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
 user_id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 login varchar(20) UNIQUE,
 pass varchar(20),
 user_name varchar(20),
 surname varchar(20),
 PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
)
```

Model:

```
@Entity
 @Table(name="users", catalog="maximodb")
 public class User implements Serializable{

@Id
@Column(name="user_id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy =GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer userId;

@Column(name = "login", unique = true, length = 20)
private String login;

@Column(name = "pass", length = 20)
private String pass;

@Column(name = "user_name", length = 20)
private String userName;

@Column(name = "surname", length = 20)
private String surname;


@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "users_roles", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "role_id") })
private Set<Role> userRoles = new HashSet<Role>();

public User() {
}

public User(String login, String pass, String userName, String surname) {
    this.login = login;
    this.pass = pass;
    this.userName = userName;
    this.surname = surname;
}


public Integer getUserId() {
    return this.userId;
}

public void setUserId(Integer userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}

public String getLogin() {
    return this.login;
}

public void setLogin(String login) {
    this.login = login;
}

public String getPass() {
    return this.pass;
}

public void setPass(String pass) {
    this.pass = pass;
}

public String getUserName() {
    return this.userName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}

public String getSurname() {
    return this.surname;
}

public void setSurname(String surname) {
    this.surname = surname;
}

public Set<Role> getUserRoles() {
    return userRoles;
}

public void setUserRoles(Set<Role> userRoles) {
    this.userRoles = userRoles;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((login == null) ? 0 : login.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((pass == null) ? 0 : pass.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((surname == null) ? 0 : surname.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((userId == null) ? 0 : userId.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((userName == null) ? 0 : userName.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((userRoles == null) ? 0 : userRoles.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    User other = (User) obj;
    if (login == null) {
        if (other.login != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!login.equals(other.login))
        return false;
    if (pass == null) {
        if (other.pass != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!pass.equals(other.pass))
        return false;
    if (surname == null) {
        if (other.surname != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!surname.equals(other.surname))
        return false;
    if (userId == null) {
        if (other.userId != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!userId.equals(other.userId))
        return false;
    if (userName == null) {
        if (other.userName != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!userName.equals(other.userName))
        return false;
    if (userRoles == null) {
        if (other.userRoles != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!userRoles.equals(other.userRoles))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

}

And now... dao function (two variants):

The first:

```
List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();

    users = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
        .createQuery("from User where login= :login")
        .setString( "login", login )
        .list();

    if (users.size() > 0) {
        return users.get(0);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
```

Returned sql:

```
select
    user0_.user_id as user_id1_1_,
    user0_.login as login2_1_,
    user0_.pass as pass3_1_,
    user0_.surname as surname4_1_,
    user0_.user_name as user_nam5_1_ 
from
    maximodb.users user0_ 
where
    user0_.login=?
```

And the second variant:

```
    Criteria criteria =  sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(User.class);
    List<User> a = (List<User>) criteria.list();

User us = a.get(0);


    return us;
```

Returned sql:

```
select
    this_.user_id as user_id1_1_0_,
    this_.login as login2_1_0_,
    this_.pass as pass3_1_0_,
    this_.surname as surname4_1_0_,
    this_.user_name as user_nam5_1_0_ 
from
    maximodb.users this_
```

The second variant is quite correct and gets user from the db. But in the first case there is a null pointer exception instead of User object. What is incorrect?
It is worth to higilight that generated sql works good in MySql Workbench (first case).

Comment: Is my answer worked for you?

Comment: I temporary have the other problem with the project :(. But when I solve it I will back to it and give the feedback. Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 0):

The first variant try to get a user with the given login but no user found for this login (verify that there is a user with the given login in database).
The second variant list all users in the database and than get the first one. Your User table contain some users that's why this variant return a user and not null.